# How to add pin on Google Map when location is changed in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

i am use google map. first time pin is added, and when location is changed the pin is override with first last one. I want add new pin on location when location is changed every time. 
so anybody can help me please.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{

location_updated = [locations lastObject];

NSLog(@"updated coordinate are %@",location_updated);

latitude1 = location_updated.coordinate.latitude;

longitude1 = location_updated.coordinate.longitude;


NSLog(@"%f,%f",latitude1, longitude1);
self.lblLat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude1];
self.lblLon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitude1];

url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",latitude1,longitude1]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection)
{
    webData1 = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude1,longitude1);
    marker.title = @"Ahmedabad";
    marker.snippet = @"India";
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m2.png"];
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this with this updateLocation method in ios 7.

and for adding multiple marker you have to use GMSMarker class.